# How can I increase my Graphics Card's video memory on my HP Probook 4510s? It's currently 64MB on the Mobile Intel GMA 4500HD

Tags: memory

How can I increase my Graphics Card's video memory on my HP Probook 4510s? It's currently 64MB on the Mobile Intel GMA 4500HD.

I can't find any option in the BIOS. I have the updated HP 68PZI BIOS. I have 4 GB system RAM available.

Comment: Any reason you want to increase the graphics memory ?

Comment: There is a game I'd like to play which requires 128MB minimum to run. I have 4 GB system RAM available. It should be possible thru the BIOS but I can't find any option.

Comment: If it is not in the BIOS. then it is not possible sorry. That is the major downside of notebooks. GMA Graphcis cards are highly embedded processors that lack allot of full blown functionality. You can try and hack the game installer to ignore the 128MB requirement limit. BUt you wont be able to trick it into thinking you have more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graphics memory on laptops feeds off of a certain percentage of the system memory. If you want more graphics memory, add more RAM. If your laptop can't take more ram, then you will also be unable to upgrade the graphics ram without a new system.

Comment: I have 4 GB system RAM available, so plenty of it and I just want to increase the video memory to 128MB from 64.

Comment: Sounds like your BIOS doesn't support changing how much system ram it takes for video ram. So, unfortunately, you're stuck with this one.

Comment: "The graphics memory on laptops feeds off of a certain percentage of the system memory" -- this statement is not always true.

Comment: @RyanGooler, you should update your Answer with the comment because the comment turned out to be the more accurate answer. Or just remove the bit about the certain percentage of memory.

Comment: Adding more ram directly in almost 80% will not increase the ram avaialbne for GFX. Higher end gaming notebooks(ie alien ware with full chipsets) are usually the ones with this option.. but you still set it in the BIOS, it not automatic! Embedded GFX usaully are very restricted to options in the BIOS and pre defined values from vendor 64,128,256,512. And even if you have 1gb.. you can set GFX to use 512MB and only have 512 for the system.